# Constant phase for each frequency?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, signal-analysis, phase, magnitude

FFT of some signal $x$ has two parts: $|x|$, which is the magnitude spectrum and $arg(x)$, which is the phase spectrum. I want each frequency to have the same phase. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Forcing each frequency to have the same phase will result in a counter-intuitive signal. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Why it would be counter-intuitive?

Comment: Each phase the same relative to what point in time?  2 different frequencies will have 2 different phases most of the time.

Comment: Because it's a generalization of saying `the phase must be zero` (i.e. the signal's FFT has to be real-valued).  That means that the signal will be non-causal, and exhibit symmetry about the origin.  Requiring a non-zero constant phase will just multiply the non-causal, symmetric signal by a complex constant --- making *that* signal complex-valued.

Comment: Are you looking for a filter that does not affect the phase?